# Decidability of fragments of many-sorted first-order logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory, decidability

In applications of logic, it is rare to find a unique domain of discourse. I.e. it is customary to have to speak of different entities, as Hao Wang's puts it, for instance in geometry you need to talk about points, lines and planes.

I'm surprised that there seems to be no resources like say the book "The Classical Decision Problem" addressing the decidability of fragments of this logic. The papers I could find have a limited scope. For instance, "Decidable fragments of many-sorted logic" by Abadi et alii. are severely restricted. In my particular application, I cannot have a function $f: A \times I \times C \to A$ since the fragment enforces that the two $A$'s should have different "levels".

Please correct me if I'm wrong regarding this gap in the literature. Moreover, is there a reason for this status of things? I.e. is there a reason that makes many-sorted logic decidability much more complex?

Comment: You should be able to fake having many sorts by combining all of the sorts into a single domain and then having predicates for membership in each sort. You may be interested in $MSO_2$, the monadic second order logic of graphs, which allows for vertices and edges and sets of vertices and sets of edges. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_of_graphs#Second_order

Comment: Following on TomKern's comment, the issue is not that many-sorted logic is too complex, but rather that for most purposes it is no more complex than single-sorted logic. So for historical reasons and for simplicity, people usually stick to single-sorted logic.

Comment: @TomKern Right, but does the transformation you describe preserve decidability of the associated satisfiability problem?

Comment: If there are only finitely many sorts, given a formula in the single-sort language just try all possible assignments of sorts to the variables and determine if any of them are satisfiable. I'm not sure about the case of infinitely many sorts.